# How is it that we can add the java method calls what kind of path set up is required being called from the xsl?

Tags: java, xml

Here is my code which am calling java method in XSL and my question is..
can classes should be kept in a server env?

```
    <xsl:template name="RootToAcknowledgeInventoryRequirement">
    <xsl:variable name="today" select="datetime:date()" />
    <xsl:variable name="OrganizationCode"><xsl:value-of select="$PromiseHeader/@OrganizationCode" /></xsl:variable>

    <_inv:AcknowledgeInventoryRequirement releaseID="">
        <_wcf:ApplicationArea>
            <oa:CreationDateTime xsi:type="udt:DateTimeType">
                <xsl:value-of select="datetime:dateTime()" />
            </oa:CreationDateTime>
```

Comment: The interaction of XSLT and Java depends on which XSLT processor you are using; you need to tell us. And in any case, the question isn't at all clear. What does "can classes should be kept" mean?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur response.. Am using 1.0 XSLT processor and am using Note pad ++ Tool for integrating Java code with XSLT stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to understand the question here .. correct me if it's wrong..

You have XSL code and sample XMLs. The tranformation is invoked from a Java code. Whereas you call Java methods inside XSL code itself which are residing in some other class files.

Well. The answer is simple. Merge those class files with Host program (project) that is invoking. Each class file will be a *.java file.

SDKs like Eclipse readily allow you to do this. Main class which invokes Transformation will be executable and others will be helpers.

Coming back to whether file should be residing in server or not.. Now since your code of invoking Tranformation has to reside in server. So should be the associative files.

Let me know if you need further more clarifications or concerns if you have.